# (de)Serializing stream using System.Text.Json

Tags: asp.net, .net, json-deserialization, jsonserializer, system.text.json

I am trying to serialize an object into a MemoryStream  using **System.Text.Json's JsonSerializer**. I am unable to find the implementation/method of that in the documentation. Can someone share the sample implementation for serialization and deserialization using System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**

.NET 6 added [JsonSerializer.Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-serialize-1(system-io-stream-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) overloads that write to a stream. It's now possible to write just :

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(stream,myObject);
```

This produces unindented JSON using UTF8 without BOM

---

**Original Answer**

It's unclear what the problem is, or what documentation and examples are missing, as there's are *multiple* sections in `learn.microsoft.com` and hundreds of blog posts and articles. In the docs [JSON serialization and deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview?pivots=dotnet-5-0) is a good place to start and [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) includes the section [Serialize to UTF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#serialize-to-utf-8).

A [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-5.0) is just a Stream wrapper over a `byte[]` array anyway, so serializing to a `MemoryStream` is the same as serializing to a `byte[]` array directly. This can be done with [JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetoutf8bytes?view=net-5.0):

```
byte[] jsonUtf8Bytes =JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(weatherForecast);
```

And finally, in .NET anything that needs to serialize to something, works through Reader and Writer objects, like TextReader, StreamReader, TextReader and -Writers. In JSON.NET's case, this is done through the [Utf8JsonWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter?view=net-5.0) object. [JsonSerializer.Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-5.0) has an overload that writes to a `Utf8JsonWriter` :

```
using var stream=File.OpenWrite(somePath);
using var writer=new Utf8JsonWriter(stream);
JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer,myObject);
```

That's the *slow* way of using `System.Text.Json` though. Using buffers means allocating them and cleaning them up, which is costly, especially in web applications. For this reason, ASP.NET Core uses [IO pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) instead of streams to receive and send data to sockets, using reusable buffers leased from buffer pools and passed along each step in the ASP.NET Core pipeline. Passing `byte[]` buffers around copies their contents, so .NET Core introduced the `Span<>` and `Memory<>` types, which represent a *view* over an existing (possibly pooled) buffer. This way, ASP.NET Core passes those "views" of the buffers around, not the buffers themselves.

`System.Text.Json` was built to use pipelines and reusable memory instead of streams, allowing ASP.NET Core to use minimal memory and as few allocations as possible in high traffic web sites. ASP.NET Core uses the [Utf8JsonWriter(IBufferWriter)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonWriter__ctor_System_Buffers_IBufferWriter_System_Byte__System_Text_Json_JsonWriterOptions_) constructor to write to the output pipeline through a [PipeWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipewriter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0).

We can use the same overload to write to a reusable buffer with an [ArrayBufferWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1?view=net-5.0). That's the equivalent of using a `MemoryStream` *BUT* the output is accessed through either a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` or `Memory<byte>` so it doesn't have to be copied around :

```
using var buffer=new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>(65536);
using var writer=new Utf8JsonWriter(buffer);
JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer,myObject);

ReadOnlySpan<byte> data=buffer.WrittenSpan;
```